# Database: best practice on record lock status of resources?

Tags: database, locking

Whats the best practice on record lock status of a resource?
For example, the app is about car renting.
the car should not be rented to someone else if it is already rented.

do I need simply add a column "inUse" in the database?

Answer (score 1):

use a database field as flag to markdown the car as already on rent. you can use database field such as `is_on_rent` as TinyInt and will be updated as 0 and 1 only to represent the rent status.